# How to load hidden special characters using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, file, text

We are loading data (having uni-code characters) from the text file using SSIS. However, some strings have hidden Unicode characters which do not appear at database however when we check the same string from UI it looks differently. How can I fix the problem? We try to identify these hidden characters using SQL and replace corresponding Unicode character but it showing the blank space.

String in file and Database: 'BJRNSON'
String in UI/notepad ++/other text editors: BJ?RNSON
Correct String/expected string to load is: 'BJØRNSON'

Comment: You might need a screenshot to bring in that ugly character. I attempted formatting as code hoping to allow it through in the question, but it stripped it instead. For those folks scratching their heads at that last sentence, hit the "edit" button and the character will be shown.

Comment: It could simply be that you exported that Unicode text to a file using a single-byte code that can't represent some characters. Those characters will be replaced by `?` or �. Or it could be that the data was loaded from an ASCII file using the wrong codepage. Again, characters that don't match will be replaced with `?` or `�`.

Comment: In all cases it's not an SSIS or SQL Server error, it's a conversion error caused by mixing up ASCII and Unicode. It could even be that the "UI" (what UI?) is the thing that causes the problem, either because it converts text to ASCII or uses a font that doesn't include those characters

Comment: BTW StackOverflow is an ASP.NET site that stores text in SQL Server using Unicode (nvarchar) fields. That's why you were able to post `BJØRNSON` and have it display without any problems. Conversion problems like the one you describe are always caused when ASCII is involved

Comment: `We try to identify these hidden characters using SQL and replace corresponding Unicode character` that's because there aren't any. `Ø` is no more special than `R` as far as Unicode is concerned. If the problem was caused by improper *import* or because the field was `varchar`, the data was probably destroyed (not just mangled) during the INSERT operation. Again, that's an application problem, the *application* tried to insert Unicode in an ASCII field

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, Thank you for your response. 'UI' means user interface, when I verify the string from front end application the hidden characters showing as ? or � however in sql server database the hidden characters not showing.

Comment: As you explained I tried to find the hidden characters using sql and wanted to replace them with correct character however sql finding that position as blank spaces. And it is not the issue with SSIS or SQL as you mentioned since expect hidden characters remaining Unicode string from loading properly

Comment: My questions is how can I identify these hidden charactes from the inut file to load properly or do I need to request file provider to send the file with correct strings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191315/discussion-between-prasad-kada-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Code Page from 1252 to 65001 which is a standard UTF-8 encoding and allows all type of special characters.

[image]

Comment: This wil only work if the file is already UTF8. Otherwise it will *cause* problems

Comment: Hi Srikar, We have already this configuration enabled in the package. There are some hidden characters which I could not able to load.